# How to create and compare variables in XSLT?

Tags: xslt-2.0

How do I create `aff/@id` and `xref/@rid` values for xref element using XSLT, and compare the `xref/sup` with the `aff/sub` value?

Input xml:

```
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Mochizuki</surname>
<given-names>Taku</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff_ "><sup> </sup></xref>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff_ "><sup> </sup></xref>
</contrib>
</contrib-group>
<aff id="aff_ "><sub> </sub>Departments of ...... Yokohama, Japan</aff>
<aff id="aff_ "><sub> </sub>Department of  ...... Yokohama, Japan</aff>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  As it stands we can't see what you have already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: @Mohd Javed, Can you give us the actual example of input and what's you expecting  output. it will help us to understand the problem and answer you. Thank you!